# Can I use model which is trained using Keras to Scala?

Tags: python, keras, scala

I train the NLP classification model using Keras by Python. 
But to deploy the trained model to a platform I need to use Scala.

Can I use Scala with Keras model what I trained using Python?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yep, check this blog: https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-keras-deep-learning-models-with-java-62d80464f34a

Dump your model as `.h5` like you normally would and load it in java using those libs from blog.

Another idea would be to create separate AI microservice in python(django/flask). That's what I usually do.